# Real prepaid sim card in Britain

Tags: uk, cellphones, pre-pay, gsm-mobile

I would like to have a British sim card for identification purposes mostly, e.g. registering on food ordering services. So I do not want a subscription and pay monthly. I would like to buy some gigabytes and only top up when I used that. I have found this page:

https://kenstechtips.com/index.php/best-payg-sim-for-low-usage

In theory, these are pay as you go, but the fine print contains expressions that go to the direction of auto renewal, or that the plan is for one month only, or monthly rolling.

Is there a real prepaid sim card in Britain?

Comment: Can you point out the specific expressions you are referring to? That would help us understand exactly what (potential) issue you are thinking of. Did you read the intro and especially the “Minimum Usage Requirements” section?

Comment: You need to search for classic PAYG and see if that suits your needs. I got something like this for an older neighbour. Check first though as my memory may be paying tricks on me.

Comment: Do you mean this wort of thing?  https://www.1pmobile.com/

Comment: [Giffgaff](https://www.giffgaff.com/sim-only/compare) does a PAYG SIM, just top up when you need to AFAIK

Comment: Regarding the title and last line of your question: what do you mean by a "real prepaid" SIM ? One that does not expire? Asked another way: how is a prepaid SIM that expires not "real" ?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Back in the days I had a prepaid that did not require any monthly action. A top-up was valid for a year as I remember.

Comment: @Gergely there's no prepaid sim that will never expire. They all expire. But some after 3 months, some after 6 months. Depends on the network.

Answer (score 10):

I use [GiffGaff](https://www.giffgaff.com/freesim-international) in the UK for similar reasons. You have to nudge it every six months or so to keep it active:

> To keep a  sim active you need to do one or more of the following
> things once in any 186 day period
>
> Make a least one call, SMS or MMS to another number... emergency calls
> (i.e. 999/112) and SMS/calls to giffgaff services (i.e.
> 2020,43431,43430 do not apply)
>
> Make at least one connection to the internet (data)
>
> Make a least one topup/purchase of either credit or a
> goodybag

You get the SIM by post and if you are not already in the UK, you can get it sent to your current location:

> Your SIM will arrive within in 3-5 business days in Europe or from 5
> business days for the rest of the world.